# How does one currently convert the datastore's timestamps to local time in appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pytz

I have a fairly simple scenario that I am having a difficult time finding what would seem to require a simple answer! I have an audit log in my application that has the time an action was performed stored via `auto_now_add` on a timestamp field.

I've been searching around and gae-pytz is thrown around as an answer very commonly, but it hasn't been updated in well over a year:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gaepytz

This makes me wonder if there's something incredibly simple I'm overlooking, or new functionality added that I can't find any documentation on.

All I need is to display the datastore's UTC timestamps as one specific timezone, and perhaps to do some basic filtering based on this timezone's point of reference. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180889/getting-current-time-with-timezone-in-python

Comment: Since that is over one year old I would like to confirm that that information is current